# a question about a measurable property of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a 2-d plane, let $A$ be the set of all points inside a circle $C$ and $P$ be the set of all points on the perimeter of the circle $C$. Is there any generalized measure in set theory which distinguishes between two such sets ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. It's called the [Hausdorff measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure).

Answer (score 2):

The area of A is positive, while the area of P is zero.  Did you mean to distinguish between the interior of the circle and the closure of that set (i. e. the union of the perimeter and the interior)?